# How to extract first observation of the day in dataframe?

Tags: r, timestamp

I have this dataframe containing a date column, and a unique ID. I would simply want to extract the first observation of each day.

I tried to use the dpylr package (aggregate function) and date function but I'm still a beginner in R. I also tried to look for an answer on this forum without success. Thnx in advance for your return !

Here is the situation:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(2013-01-12 07:30:00, 2013-01-12 12:40:00, 2013-01-16 06:50:00, 2013-01-16 15:10:00, 2013-01-14 11:20:00, 2013-01-14 08:15:00),
      c(A,B,E,F,C,D))
```

The outcome should be:

```
2013-01-12 07:30:00 A 
2013-01-14 08:15:00 D
2013-01-16 06:50:00 E
```

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(lubridate::ymd(date)) %>% slice(1)` if time unorder then use `arrange` before `slice`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. Note, that I have edited your example data.

```
library(dplyr)

    df <- data.frame(date = as.POSIXct(c("2013-01-12 07:30:00",
                                         "2013-01-12 12:40:00",
                                         "2013-01-16 06:50:00",
                                         "2013-01-16 15:10:00",
                                         "2013-01-14 11:20:00",
                                         "2013-01-14 08:15:00")),
                     id = letters[1:6]) 

df %>% 
  group_by(as.Date(date)) %>% 
  filter(date == min(date))
```

The result should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   as.Date(date) [3]
  date                id    `as.Date(date)`
  <dttm>              <fct> <date>         
1 2013-01-12 07:30:00 a     2013-01-12     
2 2013-01-16 06:50:00 c     2013-01-16     
3 2013-01-14 08:15:00 f     2013-01-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `aggregate` from `stats` package, also editing your dataset definition:

```
df <- data.frame(times=strptime(c('2013-01-12 07:30:00', '2013-01-12 12:40:00', 
                                  '2013-01-16 06:50:00', '2013-01-16 15:10:00', 
                                  '2013-01-14 11:20:00', '2013-01-14 08:15:00'), 
                                  format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 
                                  id=c('A','B','E','F','C','D'))
df$day <- as.Date(df$times, format='%Y-%m-%d') #create a day column
aggregate(times ~ day, data = df, FUN='min')

#  day               times
# 1 2013-01-12 2013-01-12 07:30:00
# 2 2013-01-14 2013-01-14 08:15:00
# 3 2013-01-16 2013-01-16 06:50:00
```